# Animation Node Multiple Dimension Value

Tags: animation-nodes

[image]

[image]

I can only manipulate one dimension attribute in animation node. If a single one is activated, like dimensions.x others; dimensions.y or z are just ignored.

I would like to manipulate all of them, so how can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Dimensions** - is a vector value. You can get vector value from 3 different floats by using **combine vector** node:

[image]